# Retrieving the lotto numbers - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, https

I'm looking for feedback as to how I've structured the async calls, and If anything should be written differently.

**endpoints.js**

```
module.exports = {
  lotto: 'https://www.norsk-tipping.no/api-lotto/getResultInfo.json?drawID=',
  keno: 'https://www.norsk-tipping.no/api-keno/getResultInfo.json?drawID=',
  extra: 'https://www.norsk-tipping.no/api-extra/getResultInfo.json?drawID=',
  vikinglotto: 'https://www.norsk-tipping.no/api-vikinglotto/getResultInfo.json?drawID=',
  joker: 'https://www.norsk-tipping.no/api-joker/getResultInfo.json?drawID=',
  eurojackpot: 'https://www.norsk-tipping.no/api-eurojackpot/getResultInfo.json?drawID='
};
```

**service.js**

```
var request      = require('request');
var gametypes    = require('./endpoints');

function toJSON(response){
    var data    = response.toString(),
        result  = data.match(/(^{[\s\w\W]+}$)/gm).join('');

    return JSON.parse(result);
}


function getResults(opts, callback){
    var url                     = gametypes[opts.type],    
        fromDrawID              = opts.fromDrawID,
        toDrawID                = opts.toDrawID,
        numberOfRequestsWanted  = toDrawID - fromDrawID,
        numberOfRequestsDone    = 0,
        data                    = [];

    //If either the object is missing or
    //the object with no key of 'type' is passed in - return error. 

    if(!opts.type){
        return callback(new Error('Missing required param: Object with key: type'), null);
    }


    if(fromDrawID && toDrawID) {
        console.log('Fetching the requested results from https://www.norsk-tipping.no...');

        while(fromDrawID <= toDrawID) {
            doRequest(url + fromDrawID++, callback);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Fetching the latest result from https://www.norsk-tipping.no...');
        doRequest(url, callback);
    }

    function doRequest(url, callback) {

        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            if(!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                data.push(toJSON(body));

                if(numberOfRequestsDone++ === numberOfRequestsWanted) {
                    return callback(null, data);
                } 

            } else {
                return callback(error, null);
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = getResults;
```

**example usage**

```
var lotto    = require('./service');
var options  = { type: 'vikinglotto', fromDrawID: 1, toDrawID: 500};


lotto(options, function(err, results) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    else {        
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello! Please don't make changes to the original post once it has been reviewed, as that invalidates the current answers. Please see our meta side on [performing iterative reviews](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765) for more information!

Comment: @syb0rg I didn't change any of the original content - just added to it. But if that's not allowed - no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting you move to using promises instead of callbacks. This way, you don't have to do the tango with calling callbacks, collecting results and all. You can simply replace the `request` module with the [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) module.

```
function getResult(options){
  ...
  return doRequest(options);
}

...

lotto(options).then(results => console.log(data), err => console.log(err));
```

There's little merit of putting `doRequest` inside `getResults`. It's only being used in `getResults` but it's not exposed anyways. Suggesting you move it out into the module.

JavaScript doesn't have default argument values (yet) but you can easily do the same thing using `Object.assign`. Provide a default object, and merge to a new object the defaults and the one from the arguments. This way, you avoid having to do a lot of default logic and value checks.

```
var defaults = {...}

function getResults(options){
  var mergedOptions = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);
  ...
}
```

Back to promises, firing multiple async calls in parallel using callbacks will require you to collect results and keep checking if all the requests have responded. When using Promises, you can easily use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to listen to an array of promises.

```
var request = require('request-promise');

function getResult(options){
  ...
  var drawRange = toDrawID - fromDrawID;

  // Create an array of drawIds and map them to promises
  var promises = Array(drawRange).fill(fromDrawID).map((fromDrawID, i) => {
    return request(url + (fromDrawID + i));
  });

  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What did you mean by "...Suggesting you move it out into the module"? The doRequests is used twice inside the getResults. Isn't it logical to place the function there since that's the only place I use it?

Comment: @Nilzone- You wouldn't want to redeclare functions on every call.

Comment: One thing - the fill-function don't work the way you intended to. The array is just filled with the same id (never incremented). I had to do this instead of fill `Object.keys([...Array(numberOfRequestsWanted)])`

Comment: @Nilzone- Ahh, my mistake. However, you can fill in `fromDrawID` for all items and use `array.map`'s second argument (a zero-based index) to add to the ID.

Comment: But I would also like to parse the response to proper json before I actually return Promise.all. I updated my question - is this a proper way to do it?

Comment: @Nilzone- You can attach a `then` whose success callback returns a modified value, i.e.: `return request(...).then(result => modify(result))`. The promise returned will use the modified result instead of the original resolved value.

Comment: I wasn't allowed to update my answer - so here's a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/GgbCv4ii